# Python 2D array multiplication table

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to refresh my Python. I made this code to print a 5x5 multiplication table but I'm just getting a repeating pattern of 0 4 8 12 16. What am I doing wrong?

```
#make a 2-d array that's a 5x5 multiplication table

rows, cols = (5, 5)

my_multiplication_array = [[0]*rows]*cols

for i in range(rows):
  for j in range(cols):
    my_multiplication_array[i][j] = i*j
    
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
      print(my_multiplication_array[i][j], end="")
      print(" ", end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually construct your 5x5 multiplication table using list comprehension like this :

```
my_multiplication_array = [[i*j for j in range(cols)]  for i in range(rows)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over y, create a table, iterate over x, and populate the sub table with x*y.

```
table = []
for y in range(1, 6):
    sub_table = []
    for x in range(1, 6):
        sub_table.append(x*y)
    table.append(sub_table)

for t in table:
    print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

The last iteration makes the inner list of the list equal to the values of it.

Thats because python treats these as same memory addresses

```py
>>> a = [[0]*5]*2
>>> a[1][2] = 2
>>> a
[[0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 0]]
```

Here you see I only changed one of the list but it changed both, why? Because python is treating the list equivalent to this

```py
>>> b = [0]*5
>>> a = [b]*2
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Here if you change one value in `b` it will change it in `a` also because, `a` is `b` but just nested two times.

```py
>>> b[1] = 2
>>> a
[[0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> b
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

You can achieve what you want by doing it like this:

```py
>>> my_multiplication_array = [[0]* rows for  _ in range(cols)]
```

Comment: ahh got it. I was confused because I'm more experienced in Java and I think the way I did it would've worked in Java